# Sorting files based on time in Linux

Tags: linux

I want to get a list of pathnames of files, divided by one blank space, and the files are sorted based on creation time.
I use

```
find $dir -type f -printf '%T+\t%p\n' | sort -n
```

to sort them, but the problem is, how can to delete all the time before the pathnames?

If I use

```
find $dir -printf '%p'
```

I can get a list of pathnames, but I don't know how to sort them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **cut**

```
find $dir -type f -printf '%T+\t%p\n' | sort -n | cut -f2
```